# not able to download or open blank PDF file PHP

Tags: php, firefox, pdf

I am facing some problems while generating PDF reports from my application in firefox(ubuntu machine).

my code is:

```
<?php
$path = "path_to_file" ;
$file = "test.pdf";
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
readfile($path);
return new Response("Success");
```

code is working:

- when the PDF-report contains data
- when size is more than 1 kb
- In windows machine

not working:

- when report contains no data or size is in bytes.
- It is Generating a binary sting in a new tab in browser instead of generating blank-PDF.

Please help me fixing this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: *not working: when report contains no data* - If by that you mean the document has no pages, then there is your issue, PDF viewers normally require a PDF to have a page. If you are not sure, please share a sample non-working PDF.

Comment: Hi @mkl .. i am using same code for 2 different approaches.when $path='/var/www/output',i am able to read the file(even blank one)..but when $path location is outside local server,i.e,'/home/user/Documents/output',not able to read file.Please suggest..

Comment: @adarsha hota: Then it's an open_basedir restriction or a simple permission problem.

Comment: @hellcode: while downloading pdf from my application,its changing the 'user:group' to 'www-data:www-data' instead of 'user:user'.May be for this,its not able to read/open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer.This may help others.

```
<?php
$path = "path_to_file" ;
$file = "test.pdf";
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= $file"); //Tell the filename to the browser
header("Content-type: application/pdf");//Get and show report format 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
readfile($path); //Read and stream the file
get_curret_user();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way to avoid some problems with browser applications and caching. Give it a try:

```
<?php
$path = "path_to_file" ;
$file = "test.pdf";

$content = file_get_contents($path);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($content));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $content;
die();
```

---

EDIT:

If it's really necessary to use the pdf plugin of the browser instead of downloading and opening it immediately with the associated default pdf reader, please replace

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
```

with

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks @hellcode for your valuable solution.Its directly downloading the file,but i need to open in browser also...can you pls help!!!

Comment: @adarsha hota: see my edit and take care NOT to use the newline (\n) of the header in your question